# Finding object by index, HashMaps or looping through an ArrayList? Which is fastest? (Java)

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist, indexing, hashmap

Currently in my game, if I want to find a player by their unique id I do something like this:

```
public Player getPlayerByID (int id) {
    for (Player player : playerList) {
        if (player.getId() == id)
            return player;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Would using a java HashMap be faster for indexing a player? Using something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Player> playerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Player>();

//Some method to fill hash map with players...

//Get player method
public Player getPlayerByID (int id) {
    playerMap.get(id);
}
```

Comment: yes it would. [check this for further reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702087/java-performance-map-vs-list).

Comment: @KevinEsche I'd actually say your link is a good duplicate candidate.

Comment: Oh, I couldn't find that one, I think I was searching with the wrong keywords. Thanks for your help!