# ArrayList .get faster than HashMap .get?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, hashmap

I had thought that `HashMap`s were faster for random access of individual values than `ArrayList`s . . . that is, to say, that `HashMap.get(key)` should be faster than `ArrayList.get(index)` simply because the `ArrayList` has to traverse every element of the collection to reach its value, whereas the `HashMap` does not.  You know, `O(1)` vs `O(n)` and all that.

**edit:** So my understanding of `HashMap`s was/is inadequate, hence my confusion.  The results from this code are as expected.  Thanks for the many explanations.

So I decided to test it, on a lark.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing
{       

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<SomeClass> alist = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<Short, SomeClass> hmap = new HashMap<>(4000, (float).75);
        ListIterator<SomeClass> alistiterator = alist.listIterator();
        short j = 0;
        do
        {
            alistiterator.add(new SomeClass());
            j++;
        }
        while(j < 4000);
        for (short i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
        {
             hmap.put(i, new SomeClass());
        }
        boolean done = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String blargh = null;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("\nEnter 1 to run iteration tests.");
            System.out.println("Enter w to run warmup (recommended)");
            System.out.println("Enter x to terminate program.");
            try
            {
                blargh = input.nextLine();
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Uh, what? Try again./n");
                continue;
            }
            switch (blargh)
            {
                case "1":
                    long starttime = 0;
                    long total = 0;
                    for (short i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                        starttime = System.nanoTime();
                        iteratearraylist(alist);
                        total += System.nanoTime() - starttime;
                    }
                    total = (long)(total * .001);
                    System.out.println(total + " ns: iterating sequentially"
                                       + " through ArrayList");
                    total = 0;
                    for (short i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
                    {
                        starttime = System.nanoTime();
                        iteratearraylistbyget(alist);
                        total += System.nanoTime() - starttime;
                    }
                    total = (long)(total * .001);                   
                    System.out.println(total + " ns: iterating sequentially"
                                       + " through ArrayList via .get()");
                    total = 0;
                    for (short i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
                    {
                        starttime = System.nanoTime();
                        iteratehashmap(hmap);
                        total += System.nanoTime() - starttime;
                    }
                    total = (long)(total * .001);           
                    System.out.println(total + " ns: iterating sequentially"
                                       + " through HashMap via .next()");
                    total = 0;
                    for (short i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
                    {
                        starttime = System.nanoTime();
                        iteratehashmapbykey(hmap);
                        total += System.nanoTime() - starttime;
                    }                   
                    total = (long)(total * .001);       
                    System.out.println(total + " ns: iterating sequentially"
                                       + " through HashMap via .get()");
                    total = 0;
                    for (short i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
                    {
                        starttime = System.nanoTime();
                        getvaluebyindex(alist);
                        total += System.nanoTime() - starttime;
                    }               
                    total = (long)(total * .001);       
                    System.out.println(total + " ns: getting end value"
                                   + " from ArrayList");
                    total = 0;
                    for (short i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
                    {
                        starttime = System.nanoTime();
                        getvaluebykey(hmap);
                        total += System.nanoTime() - starttime;
                    }           
                    total = (long)(total * .001);       
                    System.out.println(total + " ns: getting end value"
                               + " from HashMap");
                    break;
                case "w":
                    for (int i = 0; i < 60000; i++)
                    {
                        iteratearraylist(alist);
                        iteratearraylistbyget(alist);
                        iteratehashmap(hmap);
                        iteratehashmapbykey(hmap);
                        getvaluebyindex(alist);
                        getvaluebykey(hmap);
                    }
                    break;
                case "x":
                    done = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry.  Please try again.");
                    break;
            }           
        }
        while (!done);
        input.close();
    }

    public static void iteratearraylist(ArrayList<SomeClass> alist)
    {
        ListIterator<SomeClass> tempiterator = alist.listIterator();
        do
        {
            tempiterator.next();
        }
        while (tempiterator.hasNext());
    }

    public static void iteratearraylistbyget(ArrayList<SomeClass> alist)
    {
        short i = 0;        
        do
        {
            alist.get(i);
            i++;
        }
        while (i < 4000);
    }

    public static void iteratehashmap(HashMap<Short, SomeClass> hmap)
    {
        Iterator<HashMap.Entry<Short, SomeClass>> hmapiterator = 
        map.entrySet().iterator();
        do
        {
            hmapiterator.next();
        }
        while (hmapiterator.hasNext());
    }   

    public static void iteratehashmapbykey(HashMap<Short, SomeClass> hmap)
    {
        short i = 0;
        do
        {
            hmap.get(i);
            i++;
        }
        while (i < 4000);
    }

    public static void getvaluebykey(HashMap<Short, SomeClass> hmap)
    {
        hmap.get(3999);
    }

    public static void getvaluebyindex(ArrayList<SomeClass> alist)
    {
        alist.get(3999);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SomeClass
{
    int a = 0;
    float b = 0;
    short c = 0;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        a = (int)(Math.random() * 100000) + 1;
        b = (float)(Math.random() * 100000) + 1.0f;
        c = (short)((Math.random() * 32000) + 1);
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough, the code seems to warm up in stages.  The final stage that I've identified comes after around 120,000 iterations of all methods.  Anyway, on my test machine (AMD x2-220, L3 + 1 extra core unlocked, 3.6 ghz, 2.1 ghz NB), the numbers that really jumped out at me were the last two reported.  Namely, the time taken to `.get()` the last entry of the `ArrayList` (`index == 3999`) and the time taken to `.get()` the value associated with a Short key of `3999`.

After 2-3 warmup cycles, testing shows that `ArrayList.get()` takes around 56 ns, while `HashMap.get()` takes around 68 ns.  That is . . . not what I expected. Is my `HashMap` all eaten up with collisions? All the key entries are supposed to autobox to Shorts which are supposed to report their stored short value in response to `.hashcode()`, so all the hashcodes should be unique.  I think?

Even without warmups, the `ArrayList.get()` is still faster.  That is contrary to everything I've seen elsewhere, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518103/hashmap-vs-arraylist-performance-am-i-correct).  Of course, I've also read that traversing an `ArrayList` with a `ListIterator` is faster than just using `.get()` in a loop, and obviously, that is also not the case . . .

Comment: Why would the array list traverse the list ? The element is in an array at the given index. Before writing all this you could just have read the code of ArrayList to check your assumptions.

Comment: Yeah, I could see how the name would be confusing.  It's a List implemented as an array data structure.  Perhaps you're thinking of a linked list data structure, which is different.  I remember being slightly thrown off by that first time I saw it as well.

Comment: Also, for micro benchmarking, use JMH or caliper.

Comment: Try with different `hashCode()` implementation and compare results.

Comment: Big O for hashmap is O(1+α). Big O for pulling an item out of an ArrayList by index O(1)

Comment: @dystroy, I think you've raised a good point here.  Sometimes it's easy to forget that data structures provided with the JDK are more than just black boxes obscured from view.

Comment: @xdhmoore That is part of it I think, though in truth I've shown a good deal of ignorance here in comprehending the meaning of how or when ArrayList would offer O(n) performance and where HashMap would offer O(1) performance in the same scenario.  It's an oft-quoted fact, and I took it for granted as being a sweeping statement pertaining to many unrelated operations.  That's a fallacy on my part.

Comment: @RomanC Okay, I'd like to do that.  Got any links to some boilerplate hashCode() overrides that I should try?

Comment: @shinjw what you say here cuts to the heart of the matter, I think.  So the results are normal, and the question is borne of my ignorance.

Comment: @user3765373 Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/573032) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/299304/573032) links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashmaps aren't faster at retrieval of something at a known index.  If you are storing things in a known order, the list will win.

But say instead of your example of inserting everything into the list 1-4000, you did it in a total random order.  Now to retrieve the correct item from a list, you have to check each item one by one looking for the right item.  But to retrieve it from the hashmap, all you need to know is the key you would have given it when you inserted it.

So really, you should be comparing Hashmap.get(i) to

```
for(Integer i : integerList)
   if(i==value)
       //found it!
```

Then you would see the real efficiency of the hashmap.

Comment: I added a class (`SomeOtherClass`) that returns a `.hashCode()` result of 9999 (as a `short`) and used that to build a key for it when placing a single instance of it in the `HashMap`.  I stuck it at index 3999 in my `ArrayList`.  When using `.hashCode()` again to regenerate the key and "find" the element in my `HashMap`, it took around 200 ns.  Searching through the `ArrayList` (which I treated as being unsorted) took 8500ns.  Understandably, that is a "worst case" scenario with the element being stuck at the end, but it does serve to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 6):

> the ArrayList has to traverse every element of the collection to reach its value

This is not true. `ArrayList` is backed by an array which allows for constant-time `get` operations.

`HashMap`'s `get`, on the other hand, first must hash its argument, then it must traverse the bucket to which the hash code corresponds, testing each element in the bucket for equality with the given key. This will generally be slower than just indexing an array.

Answer (score 5):

`ArrayList.get(index)` acctualy uses constant time, since `ArrayList` is backed by an array, so it just uses that index in the bacing array. `ArrayList.contains(Object)` is a long operation in `O(n)` in worst case.

Answer (score 4):

Big O for `HashMap` is `O(1+α)`. Your α comes from hashcode collisions and a bucket must be traversed to check for equality.

[image]

Big O for pulling an item out of an `ArrayList` by index `O(1)`

[image]

When in doubt... draw it out...

Answer (score 2):

Both `ArrayList` and `HashMap` are backed with arrays, `HashMap` has to compute a hash code of the key from which it derives the index to use for accessing the array while for accessing an and element in the ArrayList using `get` you provide the index. So its 3 operations vs 1 operation for the ArrayList.

But whether a `List` or a `Map` is backed with an array is implementation detail. So the answer may differ depending on which implementations you use.

Comment: `ArrayList` implements [`RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html), so you can be pretty confident that `get` will be constant-time irrespective of which implementation you use.

Comment: @arshajii Yes, but not every implementation of `List`