# How to create a Grid without POJO (dynamic columns)?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

The question was asked here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18095407/how-to-create-a-grid-without-binder

However the vaadin's forum closed so i want to continue it here.

On Vaadin 14, Any recommendation on the best way to implement grid with dynamic varying number of columns. Using column Index (1,2,3...) is not a good choice for me. Let say I have a simple Json file (only 1 level: key-value) to map to a grid and this Json has an unknown list of properties.

**which approach is better in term of performance ?:**

[**Option 1**]

```js
class Data {
    private Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void set(String key, Object val) {
        values.put(key, val);
    }
    
    public Object get(String key) {
        return values.get(key);
    }
}

Grid<Data> myGrid = new Grid<>();
```

[**Option 2**]

```js
public class GridDynamicValueProvider implements ValueProvider<GridDynamicRow, Object> {

    private int columnIndex;

    public GridDynamicValueProvider(int columnIndex) {
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public Object apply(GridDynamicRow dynamicRow) {
        return dynamicRow.getValue(columnIndex);
    }

}

public class GridDynamicRow {

    private List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addValue(String value) {
        values.add(value);
    }

    public Object getValue(int columnIndex) {
        return values.get(columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: The linked Forum discussion already contains an answer. Check the GitHub link posted by me. The same method can be used with Vaadin 14 as well.

Comment: "which approach is better in term of performance" - no one will know unless you measure it for **your** workload.

Answer (score 4):

The SerializablePredicate of Vaadin accepts both function references and Lambdas, thus it is possible to use [non-POJO data types with Grid and Binder](https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-with-map) in Vaadin, although that is a bit unconventional. The key ingredients are:

```
Grid<Map<String, Integer>> grid = new Grid<>();
...
grid.addColumn(map -> map.get("column")).setHeader("Column");
```

You can also wrap the Map in custom class if you have need to protect the internals.

```
class Data {
    private Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void set(String key, Object val) {
        values.put(key, val);
    }
    
    public Object get(String key) {
        return values.get(key);
    }
}

Grid<Data> myGrid = new Grid<>();
```

As for the performance, essentially, you're comparing between using a List where you fetch by index versus a HashMap where you fetch by key. Here's a related question: [ArrayList .get faster than HashMap .get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809537/arraylist-get-faster-than-hashmap-get)

You can use also [ArrayList as Grid's type](https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-drill-down) if you can index the columns with a number.

The both approaches allow generating Grid's with varying dynamic number of columns, for example if you read the data directly from a file or have raw data backend queries.

Comment: Thanks for the advise Talu Lund.