# How do we create Vaadin Grids built to handle varying number of columns?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I'm building a Vaadin 14 application in which a file is generated based on a set of user inputs. Depending on those inputs, a varying number of columns (each of the same data type) is rendered in addition to a standard set of columns (which are always rendered). How can I build a Grid that can handle this, considering that a POJO "template" would need a fixed schema?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-with-map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Grid without POJO (dynamic columns)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663472/how-to-create-a-grid-without-pojo-dynamic-columns)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @TatuLund I found the cookbook example to be very useful. Thanks!